# touch -t errors on last Sundays of March

Tags: command-line, bug-reporting, date, coreutils

touch -t is giving me "invalid date format" errors if the date code represents 2:00:00AM through 2:59:59AM on the last Sunday in March of any year (I've checked 2023,2014,2016,2018). The weirdness of this in a core utility is blowing my mind. Is this some known bug? Is there a work-around?

Example:

```bash
$ touch -t 201603270159.59 myfile.txt #1:59AM works
$ touch -t 202303260200.00 myfile.txt #2:00AM fails
touch: invalid date format ‘202303260200.00’
$ touch -t 201603270259.59 myfile.txt #2:59AM fails
touch: invalid date format ‘201603270259.59’
$ touch -t 201603270300.00 myfile.txt #3:00AM works
$ touch -t 202303270200.00 myfile.txt #2:00AM the next day works
```

(These read YYYYMMDDHHMM.SS).

I touched a collection of 5000 files with randomly assorted timestamps ranging back 12 years. Here's a list of datetime stamps where touch fails. The problem dates are always the last Sunday of March

```bash
touch -t 201403300248.57 fileA.txt
touch -t 201403300251.21 fileB.txt
touch -t 201403300253.03 fileC.txt
touch -t 201603270252.42 fileD.txt
touch -t 201603270234.43 fileE.txt
touch -t 201803250223.39 fileF.txt
```

The bug persists if I use touch -d. For example:

```
$ touch -d "2016-03-27 02:34:43" myfile.txt
touch: invalid date format ‘2016-03-27 02:34:43’
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.03. This happens on bash, csh, sh shells.

Comment: Is this "spring ahead" or daylight savings change for your time zone?

Comment: yes! That solve it.

Comment: Thought so I started writing an answer and when you commented simply posted what was written.

Comment: What timezone are you in? Can you post the output of `timedatectl`? What type of filesystem are those files on? Say, ext4, ZFS, vfat, NTFS?

Comment: @marcelm I'm in GMT+1
$ timedatectl
Local time: Tue 2024-02-13 08:38:43 CET
Universal time: Tue 2024-02-13 07:38:43 UTC
RTC time: Tue 2024-02-13 07:38:43
Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes
NTP service: inactive
RTC in local TZ: no
Filesystem: VFS over DrvFs over NTFS (https://jsinkers.github.io/notes/notebooks/comp_sys/20_wsl.html)

Comment: @Schroeder So your time zone is [CET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time). All countries using CET observe daylight saving time, which activates on the last Sunday of March at 02:00. That means [WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer](#605954) is probably the correct explanation for what you're seeing.

Answer (score 11):

During Daylight Savings Time transition the time of 02:00 to 02:59 does not exist.

Linux / Ubuntu tracks time internally using UTC which does not observe Daylight Savings Time and works well. When converting to local time there will be a hole between 02:00 and 02:59.

Answer (score 1):

This is a daylight savings time sping-ahead bug. The problem arises from the files from which the date stamps originate were created in the USA, where daylight savings time is the second Sunday of the month. Then touch is being run on a German computer where daylight savings time is the last Sunday of the month and skips over [2:00-2:59]AM. So the American computer generates datetimes that don't exist in Germany.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be true. The place where the files were created won't be relevant, it is instead more likely to be caused by the locale settings on your computer. Try the same commands with something like `LC_ALL=C touch -t 201403300251.21 fileB.txt`, does that work?

Comment: @terdon: locale controls _format_ (like d/m/y vs m/d/y) but `touch` uses a fixed format. Timezone, including DST/summertime, is controlled by `TZ` e.g. `TZ=Etc/UTC ...`.

Comment: @terdon No, that gives the same error.

Comment: @Schroeder how about `touch -d "2016-03-27 02:34:43 UTC" file` or even `touch -d "2016-03-27 02:34:43 CEST" file`?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 of course. Sorry, I was thinking that it would also set the corresponding timezone but of course that makes no sense since you can have multiple timezones sharing a locale.

Comment: I agree this is very likely not true. On Unix filesystems, files do not "know" in which timezone they were created. They carry their timestamps as [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is not DST-aware.

Comment: @terdon
$ touch -d "2016-03-27 02:34:43" file ##Fails
touch: invalid date format "2016-03-27 02:34:43"
$ touch -d "2016-03-27 02:34:43 UTC" file ##Works
$ touch -d "2016-03-27 02:34:43 CEST" file ##Fails
touch: invalid date format "2016-03-27 02:34:43 CEST"

Comment: @marcelm
The claim isn't that files know their time zone, but rather that they carry timestamps which were set by a computer that does. What's the unlikely part?

Comment: Ah, see? It does work if you specify a time _and_ time zone so the problem will be something related to your time zone settings. I have no idea what, I don't know this sort of thing well enough, but it works with UTC and fails with CEST so it must be something like that.

Comment: @Schroeder Files on Unix filesystems carry their timestamps as [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is not DST-aware. If their timestamps have no concept of DST, they also have no concept of "being created by a computer that supports DST". There is no "invalid" unix timestamp, so no way for a computer to create one.

Comment: _But_, that applies to filesystems that store their timestamps as unix time (such as ext4). In your latest comment on your question, you mention that the underlying filesystem is NTFS. Perhaps NTFS _does_ include timezone / DST in its timestamps? I don't know.

Comment: @marcelm I think the confusion is in the details of what my operation is. I'm migrating a bunch of notes from different note taking software and the conversion process reset the creation_time. I'm extracting the markdown text timestamp metadata set by the notetaking software inside the files (ex: "created_time: 2022-10-12T13:01:41.691Z"), converting its format in python, and touching the new note files. The problem is that the old note files were created on a computer set to an American timezone, and the touch is done on a computer set to UTC+1 where some of those are invalid times.

Comment: @Schroeder Ah, I see! Yes, that would explain. It is possible for certain date/time combinations to exist in one time zone but not in another. I thought you were talking about timestamps on the file themselves, as that is what the `touch` command from your question modifies. I think everyone else made the same assumption.

Comment: However, you should be able to convert between timestamps correctly, if you use the right timezone-aware tooling. You can't simply "add an hour to UTC"; timekeeping is more complicated than that. E.g. `date -d "2016-03-27T01:34:43Z"` will handle such a case correctly. For Python, you'll need timezone-aware datetime objects, for example: `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2016-03-27T01:34:43Z").astimezone()`.